# Stack View not Showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swift5

I used storyboard to create a stack view with a button. When I launch the app however, the button does not appear.

[image: Storyboard Figure]

This is my View Controller Scene
[image: View Controller Scene]

And this is the app running, as you can see the Stack View with the button does not display at all.

[image: App Running]

In my 'VierController.swift' file I dragged both the button and the stack view

```
@IBOutlet weak var TopView: UIStackView!

@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
 }
```

I have now tried so many options, but nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to use a stack view which itself has no constraints. That's not going to work. The job of a stack view is to put constraints on whatever it contains, and it doesn't know how to do that unless you supply the stack view itself with constraints. Position and size the stack view itself with constraints; now it will show the button within itself.

(It should be mentioned, however, that making a stack view containing nothing but one button is a pointless and strange thing to do. You would be better off just having the button all by itself.)